# How to get element before and after a class using JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm stuck with a simple function.

Say I have, as a sample HTML structure:

```
<button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction-show-hide()">show or hide</button>
<div class="inner"style="display:none"> What I want to show/hide>
<button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction-hide()">hide</button>
</div>
```

I want to build a function `myfunction-show-hide()` that selects `NEXT` div of class `inner` and changes its display to `''` if it was `none` and to `none` if it was `''`.

And the reverse function, acting on `PREVIOUS` div of class `inner`.

Sounds really simple, but I am stuck!

Thank you for your help.

***** non working code below ****

```
    <button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction-show-hide()">show or hide</button>
<div class="inner"style="display:none"> What I want to show/hide>
<button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction-hide()">hide</button>
</div>

<script

  function myfunction-show-hide(){
    var x =  this.nextElementSibling;
    if (x.style.display == "none")
    {x.style.display = "";}
    else
    {x.style.display = "none"}

}
function myfunction-hide(){
    this.prev().hide(); 

}</script>
```

Another one not working:

```
function myfunction_show_hide(){
$(this).next().toggle();
```

}

```
function myfunction_hide(){
$(this).prev().hide();
```

}

Another one not working:

```
<button class="accordion" onclick="Hide()">show or hide</button>
<div class="inner" style="display:none">
What I want to show-hide 
<button class="accordion" onclick="Hide">hide</button>
</div>

<script
function Hide()
{
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
var requiredElement = elements[0];

var style = requiredElement.getAttribute("style");
if(style != "display:none")
    requiredElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
}

}</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please give a read to [ask]. One thing we like to see from questions is an indication of what you've got so far -- it may be that you're right on the cusp and just need a little push. It may be you're miles away. We don't know, so we can't give you the best guidance. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Did you try google it? Check this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: I have tried w3schools... but not so convinced of having a loop to do this. I have added some bad code in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

```js
function myfunction_show_hide(){
 $(this).next().toggle();
}

function myfunction_hide(){
 $(this).prev().hide(); 
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction_show_hide()">show or hide</button>
<div class="inner"> What I want to show/hide</div>
<button class="accordion" onclick="myfunction_hide()">hide</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work here... I can't say why.